# How mass being distributed after an explosion

Tags: space, big-bang

Consider an explosion which is taking place in a vacuum, The exploding object is very small with a huge amount of energy and high density (like a big bang explosion) and the object explodes from the energy internally. I wanted to know how the mass is going to distribute after huge explosion in every direction. Does the mass distribute equally in all direction with same velocity or differently in different direction.

Comment: Well the Big Bang was a 4D explosion (it created space & time) and isn't quite the explosions we see in our world today. Something like a [supernova](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supernova) would probably be closer to what you want.

Comment: Yeah I know that, I wanted to know how that 4D explosion takesplace

Comment: Well since there's only been *one* (observed) big bang, we can only say that *it* behaved the way it did and can't say anything about what it *could* do otherwise (i.e., it is not a repeatable event)

Comment: Just **try** to set up a FEA simulation of, say, a small block of C4 and see if you can predict the debris field.  It's just about impossible to do better than a statistical "envelope" of the level of uniformity.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this NASA JPL millisecond timescale supernova simulation video:

http://www.jpl.nasa.gov/video/?id=1279

Comment: Think that the force is internally equal in all directions, then they must move in opposite as same mass and velocity